# ionic ngFor not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic Creator and when I export the project, it doesn't have any .ts file. I have issue trying to get ngFor working for my code.

I'm using the $scope variable to pass array object from the Controller to the Template.

grocery.html (/template)

```
<ion-list id="groceriesHistory-list4">
        <ion-item class="item-icon-right" id="groceries-list-item13" ng-repeat="grocery in groceries">{{ grocery.date }}
        <span class="item-note">Free 1.5L Drink Redeemed</span>
        <i class="icon ion-android-bar"></i>
</ion-item>
```

groceryCtrl

```
firebase.database().ref("table").orderByChild("user").equalTo("userid").on("value", function(snapshot) {
        var credit = 0;
        var groceryHistory = [];
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                var childData = childSnapshot.val();
                //console.log(childData);
                if(childData.type == 1) {
                    if(childData.used == 1) {
                        groceryHistory.push(childData);
                    }
                }
            });
        console.log(groceryHistory);
        $scope.groceries = groceryHistory;
```

There is no data to display even though $scope.groceries contain at least an object.

Edit1: I edited my code for angularjs v1 but there is still no data to display.

Edit2: It is working but I have to click the sidemenu first before the data display itself.

Comment: $scope is in angular v1 you are using ngFor which is in angular v2+ version

Comment: @PareshGami I knew something was amiss. So I am supposed to use ng-repeat?

Comment: yes you have to use all syntax which are support in angular v1

Comment: Ah, the most useless words when troubleshooting code: _not working_.  It would be nice if you'd post a _proper_ description in your title, instead of _not working_.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-for` does not exists in angularjs. You need to use `ng-repeat`:

```
<ion-list id="groceriesHistory-list4">
<ion-item class="item-icon-right" id="groceries-list-item13" ng-repeat="grocery in groceries">{{ grocery.date }}
     <span class="item-note">Free 1.5L Drink Redeemed</span>
     <i class="icon ion-android-bar"></i>
</ion-item>
```

Based on your update2, your scope changes is not in a angular digest cycle. Simply put your changes in a $timeout to make sure a digest cycle will run:

```
$timeout(function(){
   $scope.groceries = groceryHistory;
})
```

Comment: I tried. But it doesn't work, there is still no data.